How to generate new Firebase token for Push Notification through FirebaseAdmin
I'm working on C# sharp project, where I want to create a new FCM Token for device who's token already got stale or expired. But condition is using FirebaseAdmin.
Or How to update expiration time of FCM Token manually?
Created a sample project with nuget FirbaseAdmin 3.0.1. Here I've checked whether tokens are valid or not without triggering the notifications on device. In case of not valid tokens, I want to create new tokens and update them on FCM too.
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fba = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
            {
                Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("key.json")
            });

            string[] tokens = new string[]
            {
                "eSPXl7bJFTM:APA91bF-kjpN31aNuUxdQh-_0QW5zHxnczq--1IIhvDLCQRfTmvmy7pxDWVA8lPrkx0Rd0PxsqS_Zf-VJgVxEW-TpbyBmOuwNgDBb8xF_MrePva2a1d1CDg3ZC3rWmyqbHXP34QE-Eyq",
                    "eHlZfQJ24UbUm2sj9w3SyW:APA91bGBy4zRN63U6nkMmyithmQsjZPZDpSPBHI72AB6CE3Pk7anvpQeDN42YUb1sbLMxD8v7DbmzP9xEbG6FyOQvzuJwMRlw8FZ3H7-yOrItVA835b-4FuT1vhRxkUcBltn_8jXnjl7",
                "eurtRHNs5o8:APA91bF79IFE5NLReK1xnTWHLP2GTGT5JBRCljK78KpjhdbRUdea2pg2reC-cS1LWuDjWiFYm086EZedwzr-I4nVWWbosilqTN2G6QpcfFkey89ZGeZ3ijzPRk3P6lxd7Zn_BHI1_0_P"
            };

            var dryRun = true;

            var response = SendNotification(tokens, dryRun).Result;
            Console.WriteLine($"Sucessfully sent[{response.SuccessCount}] notification(s), failures [{response.FailureCount}]");

            int index = 0;
            foreach (var tokenReponse in response.Responses)
            {
                if (tokenReponse.IsSuccess)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Token at index {index} is valid");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Token at index {index} is not valid. Message: {tokenReponse.Exception.HttpResponse.ReasonPhrase}");
                }

                index++;
            }

            
        }
}


While you can manage which tokens you send to on your server, tokens are retrieved and requests for generation are made on clients. To get your desired effect you should have clients update their token around monthly or have them automatically retrieve a new one on reconnecting after time away.
From that doc:
"When stale tokens reach 270 days of inactivity, FCM will consider them expired tokens. Once a token expires, FCM marks it as invalid and rejects sends to it. However, FCM issues a new token for the app instance in the rare case that the device connects again and the app is opened."
Assuming your app is configured to send your server newly issued tokens, users who run the app will get new tokens while users who are not running it will not.

Is there any way where I can create FCM Token from FirebaseAdmin for client (for Android or iOS devices with device id) and use same FCM Token for push notifications?
